# Get query from mysql database group by day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table like this:

```
id           view_time               view_cost               view_ip       ect
1           2012-05-03 00:00:00     10                      46.196.25.2   ----
2           2012-05-03 00:00:00     30                      46.196.25.2   ----
3           2012-05-03 00:00:00     20                      46.196.25.2   ----
4           2012-05-04 00:00:00     10                      46.196.25.2   ----
5           2012-05-04 00:00:00     80                      46.196.25.2   ----
6           2012-05-05 00:00:00     40                      46.196.25.2   ----
7           2012-05-05 00:00:00     50                      46.196.25.2   ----
8           2012-05-05 00:00:00     10                      46.196.25.2   ----
9           2012-05-05 00:00:00     10                      46.196.25.2   ----
10          2012-05-05 00:00:00     20                      46.196.25.2   ----
11          2012-05-05 00:00:00     10                      46.196.25.2   ----
```

And my result must like this:

```
Day          Views          Cost
2012-05-03   3              60
2012-05-04   2              90
2012-05-05   6              140
```

And i looking for Mysql query and php code for get this result

Comment: and how does your query looks like?

Comment: i wouldn't expect any accepted answers here. People (with really low reputation) who usually ask others to write complete code, putting _"it must look like this"_ or _"i need the code"_ will never accept or upvote any efforts from those who will try to help regardless of how poor the question was.

Comment: always post 4 things. sample code , structure , desired output , whatyouhavetried. Dont go asking people to do things for you. first try if you stuck we are here to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

**[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ed0cb/3)**

**[sql fiddle with date format](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ed0cb/4)**

```
select DATE(view_time) as `Day`, count(*) as `Views`, sum(view_cost) as `Cost`
from `your_table`
group by DATE(view_time)
```

Comment: why has this been downvoted?

Comment: +1 because this was posted first, and it's exactly the same as the others (or better)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the answer as such, but it adds nothing to tha canon of SO knowledge and because answering questions like this (those with no apparent research effort) sets such a poor precedent.If I'm feeling less grumpy later, I'll 'un-downvote' it!

Answer (score 0):

The sql should be quite simple

```
SELECT 
    DATE(`view_time`) AS `Day`,
    count(*) AS `Views`,
    SUM(`view_cost`) AS `Cost`
FROM
    `yourtable`
GROUP BY
    DATE(`view_time`)
```

The php code you have to create yourself

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward.

```
SELECT view_time, count(view_Time) as Views, sum(view_cost) as view_cost
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY View_time
```